# How to execute a query multiple time in mysqli Connection using PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

only work when $i=0;

```
<?php   
        include 'db.php';
        $con = new db();
        $db = $con->getConnection();
            $i = 0;
        while($i <= 10){
            $query = "call rep_summary('$date')";
            $result = $db->query($query);
            while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $user = $data['username'];
                $id = $data['id'];
                echo $user;
                }

            $i++;
        }
        $db->close();

    ?>
```

the following code work fine but its take too much time and for that I want to reuse connection

```
<?php   
   include 'db.php';

   $i = 0;
    while($i <= 10){
        $con = new db();
        $db = $con->getConnection();
        $query = "call rep_summary('$date')";
        $result = $db->query($query);
        while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $user = $data['username'];
            $id = $data['id'];
            echo $user;
            }

        $i++;

    }
$db->close();

?>
```

and db class

```
<?php

class db {

    var $_host = "localhost";
    var $_user = "root";
    var $_password = "";
    var $_database = "test";
    var $db;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new mysqli($this->_host, $this->_user, $this->_password, $this->_database);
        $this->db->set_charset("utf8");
    }

    public function getConnection() {
        if ($this->db->connect_errno > 0) {
            die('Unable to connect to database [' . $this->db->connect_error . ']');
        }
        return $this->db;
    }

}
```

How I can execute query in a single connection

Comment: move `$con = new db();$db = $con->getConnection();` outside while loop

Comment: I have used that and get Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object error in 2nd iteration

Comment: move your close function outside loop. check my answer

Comment: I have moved that code, but I still got same error

Comment: is the $date parameter set correctly?

Comment: its working very fine when I create new connection every time

Answer (score 1):

you should instantiate the db object outside of the loop, and close it after:

```
$con = new db();
$i = 0;
while($i <= 10){       
    $db = $con->getConnection();
    $query = "call rep_summary('$date')";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $user = $data['username'];
        $id = $data['id'];
        echo $user;
        }
    $i++;    
}
$db->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the db connection and close functions outside the while loop. You can execute multiple queries on same connection.

```
include 'db.php';
$con = new db();
$db = $con->getConnection();
$date = date('Y-m-d');
   $i = 0;
    while($i <= 10){

        $query = "call rep_summary('$date')";
        $result = $db->query($query);
        while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $user = $data['username'];
            $id = $data['id'];
            echo $user;
            }

        $i++;
    }
$db->close();
```